# Why my bash-git-prompt not working on Mac M1

Tags: git

> brew list

was showing bash-git-prompt

And I added the required script into .bash_profile

```
if [ -f "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
 __GIT_PROMPT_DIR="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/bash-git-prompt/share"
 source "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh"
fi
```

Comment: Your shell might be zsh. You can find your shell by typing `echo $0`. If it is zsh, try adding that required script to .zshrc and adapt it to zshell and then see if it works as desired.